# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: MY_FUNCTION not found in EJB

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic11g

I am facing an issue in my EJB code. The following is my code, which is deployed on Weblogic 10.3.3:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredFunctionQuery(name = "MY_FUNCTION", functionName = "apipay",
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
            queryParameter = "consubflag", name = "consubflag", direction = Direction.IN, type=String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
            queryParameter = "contrno", name = "contrno", direction = Direction.IN, type=String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
            queryParameter = "username", name = "username", direction = Direction.IN, type=String.class)
    },
    returnParameter = 
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
            queryParameter = "paymentid", type = String.class)
)
public class MyPayment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String paymentid;
    String consubflag;
    String contrno;
    String username;
}
```

Following is the EJB code from which I am calling:

```
Query q = tabsEntityManager.createNamedQuery("MY_FUNCTION");
q.setParameter("consubflag", "S");
q.setParameter("contrno", contrno);
q.setParameter("username", "ATMGTW");

paymentId = (String) q.getSingleResult();
```

Following is my persistence.xml:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="PU1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS1</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.MyPayment</class>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="PU2" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS2</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.MyRequest</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The complete error stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: My_FUNCTION not found.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(EJBQueryImpl.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameterInternal(EJBQueryImpl.java:1145)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:71)
        at com.warid.es.onelink.facade.TopUpControllerBean.postPaidPayment(TopUpControllerBean.java:594)
```

I tried the same code in a Java SE app and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NamedStoredFunctionQuery](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/annotations/NamedStoredFunctionQuery.html) was introduced in EclipseLink 2.3.x and according [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/WebLogic_Web_Tutorial#Oracle_WebLogic_Server_10.3.3.0) WebLogic 10.3.3.0 was shipped with EclipseLink 2.0.2.

That's why annotation is ignored during deployment and query defined in @NamedStoredFunctionQuery is not found.

Comment: Thanks for update, Can we enable EclipseLink 2.3.x support in weblogic 10.3.3?

Comment: Doesn't look too easy. You can find some connected instructions about using JPA 2 implementation behind the link: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/WebLogic_Web_Tutorial (same as in answer).